# How to record all the url of a web application using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter.I have a web application and I want to record all the possible Url in the application(like a web crawler). Is it possible to get all the Url and store it in a file.Please help in proving the solution.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) which can be used as a web crawler and/or randomizer of request parameters.

If you want to save URLs along with other sampler metrics you can override `jmeter.save.saveservice.url` property using one of the below options:

1. Add `jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true` property to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)
2. Locate `#jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false` in *jmeter.properties* file (the same location - /bin folder of your JMeter installation), uncomment it and set to `true`
3. Pass the property via `-J` command-line argument to JMeter startup script as

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   ```

Your result file will look as follows:

```
1424142574950,1001,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,1591,http://example.com/,1001
```

So URLs will be stored as penultimate column

For more information on different JMeter property types and ways of setting/overriding them check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)